# Using formulas from a text/writing to a text

Tags: java

So, my lecture powerpoint slides and even my book is not really doing a good job (for my understanding that is) of explaining how to use formulas from a text document, then when the code runs/compiles successfully it will create a "Results.txt" in the same folder.

These are the formulas in a notepad doc. Nothing to crazy, just a proof of concept 
4 * 5 ..
3 / 4...
3 - 1..
2 + 3..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFileLineByLine {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String line;
        int numberOfLines = 3;
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++){
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }

        text.Reader.close();
        return textData;

        try {
               File inputfile = new File(args[0]); //new File("formulas.txt")
               Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\Users\Frost\Documents\Question4"));
               BuffredReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\Users\Frost\Documents\Question4"));
               PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("Results.txt");           



while (input.hasNextLine()) {
      line = input.nextLine();

      System.out.println("read <" + line + ">"); // Display message to commandline             
      // Declare ArrayList of for storing tokenized formula from String line                                       

double result = 0; // The variable to store result of the operation 

   // Determine the operator and calculate value of the result 
    System.out.println(formula.get(0) + ' ' + formula.get(1) + ' ' + 
     formula.get(2) + " = " + result); // Display result to command line 

// Write result to file           
}           
// Need to close input and output files       
} 

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {            
   System.out.println("Error reading file named " + Formulas.txt);

     }   


  }  
}
```

Comment: 4 * 5.. 
3 / 4..
3 - 1..
2 + 3..

Comment: There are numerous compile-time errors there. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: ReadFileLineByLine.java:22: error: illegal escape character
               Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\Users\Frost\Documents\Question4")); ....... It has a ^ pointing to each section of that. I don't understand why. Also, if my code is going in the right direction?

Comment: To fix the illegal escape character you have to double up on the backslashes in the file path `Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Frost\\Documents\\Question4"));` otherwise it thinks the single backslash is an escape character.

Comment: Post your code again after compile errors are fixed and we can help with the logic. I think fixing the errors will help you figure out the logic as well. Ask about other errors if needed. :)

Comment: ReadFileLineByLine.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
                          
  symbol:   variable textReader. The ^ is pointing at textReader. is this because I don't have Reader initialized anywhere?

Comment: Correct. It looks like you want textReader to be a Scanner object like you did with `Scanner input`

Comment: Honestly having a hard time figuring how to format that. Scanner Reader = something? Got my book open and another computer scouring the internet. Should I even be initializing it under the TRY { ?

Comment: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Frost\\Documents\\Question4")); ......... this isn't initializing my reader?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started. The `//TODO:` comments are where you need to build your logic. Be sure to change the file paths back to what you need. I changed them to a Temp location. Also change the messages printed as I just put something there as proof of concept. I tried to comment thoroughly but don't hesitate to ask questions.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFileLineByLine {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String line = "";
    //Declare Scanner and PrintWriter outside of try clause so they can be closed in finally clause
    Scanner input = null;
    PrintWriter output = null;

    try {
        //Instantiate input and output file
        input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Temp\\test.txt"));
        output = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Temp\\Results.txt"));

        //Loop through lines in input file
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine();

            // Display message to commandline
            System.out.println("read <" + line + ">"); 

            // Populate ArrayList of tokenized formula from String line
            //TODO:

            // The variable to store result of the operation
            double result = 0; 

            // Determine the operator and calculate value of the result
            //TODO:

            // Write result to file
            output.println("Print result of " + line + " to Results.txt");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //Exception thrown, print message to console
        System.out.println("File Not Found: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        //close files in finally clause so it happens even if exception is thrown
        //I also set to null as extra precaution
        input.close();
        input = null;
        output.close();
        output = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work with this template and see if I can get it. Will comment with questions if needed!(: